# Which type to choose among ehcache embedded, standalone, server with terracotta or without terracotta for my requirement

Tags: ehcache, hazelcast, ehcache-3

I have 2/3 Java/spring-boot application running in a system. I want to use common storage so that other java application can also use cache generated by any other Java/spring-boot application.

Can I create in memory ehcache with common diskstore

```
<!--diskStore path="D://cache//" /-->
```

or should I run a standalone ehcache in my machine & use it in all application

So, as far as I read, it looks like if we need to run in a server, it should be in Terracotta server & terracotta server helps in distribution

But, I rather want to centralize the cache, so other application can use common cache

So, I think I need to do without terracotta

Or is there any other cache vendor is there to support my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved using Hazelcast IMDG. Hazelcast IMDG can be run as seperate cluster or embedded with spring applications. To use hazelcast with Spring all you have to is to add the Spring-data-hazelcast dependency. 
There are several code samples available online and it github. 
Spring Data example: [Click Here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-hazelcast-chemistry-sample/)
Dependency project : [Click here](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast)